# Running docker centos image with systemd on ECS

Tags: docker, centos, centos7, amazon-ecs

I want to run a centos container with systemd on ECS, I am able to run it locally from the information given in the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/). But the trouble is I am using Fargate as the launch type and I am not able to understand how `-v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro` in the docker run command maps to fargate launch type as the underlying instance is not in our control adn I also came across that we need to pass `--privileged` option also to run the container and can someone tell me where to place it in the task definition

Comment: Do you've any luck in running the systemd on ECS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you definitely won't be able to do that on Fargate; the whole point of Fargate is that it runs on shared infrastructure; giving a container privileged access would give you (the owner of the container) root privilege on the server (owned by Amazon and shared by others).